# Getting wordpress page template with static html content to show in searches

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have set up a Wordpress page template with static HTML in it (by making a PHP file in my child theme folder, using comment block to provide a template name, followed by HTML content, then creating a Wordpress page and assigning the template name in the page attributes).

As it stands, the page displays exactly as wanted (with URL domain.com/template-name/). The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get any of the static HTML content from my template page to show up in searches (using standard Wordpress search with known search word that is in the static HTML content).

Is there a way to get the search to include the page template's static HTML code as part of its results?

I have tried several search plugins (like Relevanssi, Ivory Search, and a few others) without any success. I also created a page using the same static HTML code (used in the page template file), but putting it in the code editor and assigning the default template -- to test the search, itself. In this context the search returned the page when using a search term known to be in the code.

```
<?php
/* A very basic example where ideally "Hello" or "World" would show up if used in a search. */

/* Template Name: Hello */

   get_header(); 

?>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<?php
   get_footer(); 
?>
```

I expected (or hoped) that the my static HTML page template would show up in the search result page, when searched using a known word in the HTML content. Unfortunately that did not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress stores all it's content in the database so that is what it is searching. I am unaware of any search plugin that extends that functionality to also search the text in your theme's templates.

Your best option is to add the text to the post's content. If unable to do that you will need to create a function to search your templates and add those results to a search filter.

Comment: I did what you suggested in regards to adding the text to the post's (in this case page) content. It did work to show up in the search; just as importantly, it didn't interfere with the page template's code. Good call on that. 

This will work for now, but down the road I may try to develop a search solution that finds the page template HTML text. If I do, I will revisit this post and publish my findings.